# Using wp_editor output correctly

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes

I'm having a problem with the wp_editor. I have a feeling it's a problem with the css in my template. 
The html being output from the wp_editor does not seem to display the same thing when echo'd onto a page as it did when it was in the WYSIWYG editor. For example if I align an image left in the editor, it looks fine, but then when the post is shown on the page it is not.

I am having this issue both with my own plugin that uses the wp_editor, and the standard blog post plugin.

Any more details please let me know

Thanks in advance

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WYSIWYG editor will give your image is an align left. However the way your page is built is unknown to the editor. A great way to overrule the editor is to add a class to your image, within the advanced settings tab of the image selection, then style it accordingly within your stylesheet.

With a link to your page we could use the dev tools to see what's going on. Without that or an screenshot we can only guess as to what the editor may or may not be doing.

Comment: I've just solved it, perhaps I was a little quick to post on here. I had to include the css classes written by wordpress as seen here: http://codex.wordpress.org/CSS#WordPress_Generated_Classes

Comment: Awesome, if my mention of the WordPress' align left helped could you mark my answer correct? Thanks